# How do I permanently post HTML form data in a PHP array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've managed to post the form data into the array, however when I return from the `topics.php` page (manually by typing the url, not being redirected) the array refreshes and returns to the original array.

How would I be able to add form data to the array permanently? I suspected it has something to do with having to manually redirect the page, however I have to include `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` as part of my assignment, therefore can't redirect using the header. I'm new to PHP so this may not be the case however.

**My Code:**

topics.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$topics = array("Musical instruments", "Programming languages", "Varieties of pizza");
$newtopic = $_POST['newtopic'];
if( isset($_POST['newtopic']) )
{
    array_push($topics, $newtopic);
}
echo json_encode($topics);
?>
```

admin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Admin Page</title>
  <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>

<style>
div.col-sm-6{
    font-size: 2em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1> Admin Page </h1>
  <p> A page to add to topics. </p>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="topic-container">
      <button name="topic-button" id="topic-button" type="button">Show Topics</button>
      <br></br>
      <h2>Topics:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-container">
        <form action="topics.php" method="post">
        <h2>New Topic:</h2>
        <input type="text" name="newtopic">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Topic">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#topic-button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("topics.php", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $(".topic-container").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
I've changed `topics.php` so it saves session variables, however this still doesn't stop the array from refreshing and returning to the original.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$topics = array("Musical instruments", "Programming languages", "Varieties of pizza");
$_SESSION["newtopic"] = $_POST["newtopic"];
if( isset($_POST['newtopic']) )
{
    array_push($topics, $_SESSION["newtopic"]);
}
echo json_encode($topics);
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at "sessions".

Answer (score 1):

The [`$_POST`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) data is part of the request you send to the server. When you submit a form using the post method the data of this form is sent with the request, but forgotten for each subsequent request.

What you want is a [`$_SESSION`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), this is a variable that can contain data for the duration of the current user's session between several requests. Remember that the session variable is unique for every visitor.

Comment: I've created a session variable, however this doesn't stop the array from refreshing.

Comment: You should put all the data from the `$_POST` variable you want to save in the `$_SESSION` variable. Also, remember to call [`session_start`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the start of your php script.